# Printing Hashes of Arrays of Hashes of Arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to create an inverted index of words and their placements in a given corpus of documents. An example of the data structure I'm aiming for is something like:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Word   |                           Location                           |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| 'word 1' | 'doc1' 'title',  'doc4' 'text', 'doc7' 'title' 'text'        |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where 'title' and 'text' are the possible locations. The above table means that 'word 1' can be found in the title of doc1, the text of doc4, and both the title and the text of doc7.

My code to parse and generate the data is:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    # determine doc no and location within docs
    ....

    #iterate words in a given location within a document 
    foreach my $str ($line =~ /[[:alpha:]]+/g) { 
        push @{ $doc{$docno} }, $location;        
        push @{ $wordlist{$str} }, $doc{$docno}; 
    }
}
```

While my code to print the data is:

```
foreach my $str (reverse sort { $wordlist{$a} <=> $wordlist{$b} } keys %wordlist) { 
    printf $fo "%-15s %-15s \n", $str, "@{ $wordlist{$str} }";
}
```

However, the result is:

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|   Word   |                           Location                           |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|  'word1' | ARRAY(0x66d4508) ARRAY(0x66d4508) ARRAY(0x66d4508)           |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Where did I go wrong?

**Edit:**

I tried changing the printing code to:

```
foreach my $str (reverse sort { $wordlist{$a} <=> $wordlist{$b} } keys %wordlist) { 
    printf "%-15s", $str;

    @arr = @{ $wordlist{$str} };
    foreach $arr (@arr)
    {
        print "@{ $arr }: , ";
    }

    print "\n";
}
```

But the result is:

```
word101        title title text text text text text text ...
```

I can't figure out how to print the document number alongside the location within said document

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I'm expecting the result to be like the table at the top of my question, but my code doesn't result in such

Comment: The table at the top contains things like `: [`. Which part of your code is supposed to produce output like that?

Comment: Oh, I'm not expecting the result to be printed exactly like that. It's just to make things easier to look at for SO users. Something which prints: ['doc3' 'title' 'text', 'doc5' 'title', ...] would be a sufficient answer for my question. I'll edit the question

Comment: OK, now you have commas in there. Which part of your code is supposed to print `,`? (BTW, I'm not trying to make you jump through hoops for our amusement. This is a hint towards the solution.)

Comment: I'm... not actually sure about the comma as the delimiter. Previously, when I'm using the structure of "push @{ $wordlist{$str} }, ($docno, $location);", the exact same code I use to print as I've written above results in: wordX 419 title 421 title 421 text

Comment: That code is equivalent to `push @{ $wordlist{$str} }, $docno, $location;`. It's adding two elements to the array. The code in your script above only adds one element, `$doc{$docno}` (which is itself a reference to another array).

Comment: Honestly, I have a difficulty in expressing myself here, as I'm not a native speaker and I've only been using Perl for a few hours.  I just want the ARRAY(0x66d4508) to be converted to something like 'doc1' 'title'. I know that $doc{$docno} is a reference to array, what I'm asking is how can I print the array itself

Comment: You'd have to dereference it (with `@{ ... }`).

Comment: I tried changing the printing code from "@{ $wordlist{$str} }" to  "@{ @{ $wordlist{$str} } }" and it doesn't print anything. In fact, it's actually the first thing I tried. Which part of my code do you specifically think I have to dereference?

Comment: You have to dereference each element of `@{ $wordlist{$str} }` separately. It doesn't make sense to nest `@{ @{ } }`.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that makes sense. I'll try doing it and then get back to you with the result. Thanks

Comment: melpomene, I've tried changing the code, but it's not working and I'm stuck now. Can you help me by pointing out where is the error? I've put my new code in my question above

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure threw the information you're after away.

Just do this:

```
while (my $line = <$fh>) { 
    # determine doc no and location within docs
    ....

    #iterate words in a given location within a document 
    foreach my $str ($line =~ /[[:alpha:]]+/g) { 
        push $worldlist{Sstr}->@*, {
            docno => $docno,
            location => $location
        };
    }
}
```

This makes the job of printing out your data structure trivial.